# Elasticsearch query is not returning correct result

Tags: php, elasticsearch

When I have a search in Kibana, it is giving me correct result. But when I implement in code, it is returning all the results. This is the query I have used:

### Kibana

```
GET movies/_search
{
  "_source": ["title"],
  "size": 20,
  "min_score": 0.5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "Legends"
          }  
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

### PHP

```
    $params = [];
    $params['index'] = $index;
    $params['size'] = 20;
    $params['min_score'] = 0.5;

    $params['query'] = [
        'bool' => [
            'must' => [
                'match' => ['title' => $searchString]
            ],
        ],
        'filter' => [],
        'should' => [],
        'must_not' => [],
    ];
```

I need to make a search in title field which has `$searchString`. Can anybody please correct me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the params array you are returning, it does not convert to the same JSON as shown in your kibana search.

The JSON from the array is this:

```json
{
  "index": "title",
  "size": 20,
  "min_score": 0.5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "title": "legends"
        }
      }
    },
    "filter": [],
    "should": [],
    "must_not": []
  }
}
```

If you want to fully match the JSON structure from the Kibana search you can change the array structure like so:

```php
<?php
// For testing purposes
$index = "title";
$searchString = "legends";
//

$params = [];
$params['_source'] = [$index];
$params['size'] = 20;
$params['min_score'] = 0.5;

$params['query'] = [
        'bool' => [
            'must' => [
                ['match' => ['title' => $searchString]]
            ],
        'filter' => [],
        'should' => [],
        'must_not' => [],
        ],
    ];
?>
```

The above changes the `index` field to `_source` and passes it as an array so that you get the array structure in the final JSON code.

It also changes the `query` array index so that the `must` index is an array of arrays which will give you the correct object array in JSON.

And sets the `filter`, `should`, `must_not` to sit under the `bool` index correctly.

Encoding the above with `json_encode` will give you the correct structure:

```json
{
  "_source": [
    "title"
  ],
  "size": 20,
  "min_score": 0.5,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "legends"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```